# Dymanic table names in codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror, hint

Requirement:
            Need to pass tablename and columnname to the sql hint using code mirror at runtime.

Problem Faced: 
Column names are passed dynamically ,where table name doesn't.

Code:
    function initAutoComplete(tablename) {
    alert(tablename);

```
         var tmptables= {

          tabledata:["a","b"]
            }
    CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function (cmeditor) {

        CodeMirror.showHint(cmeditor,'', {

            completeSingle: false,



            tables: tmptables
        });
    }
}
```

[image]
Expected is systemset.columnname

Answer (score 0):

```
var content={"AAAAAAAA": ["test"]};
function initAutoComplete() {

    CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function (cmeditor) {

        CodeMirror.showHint(cmeditor,'', {               
            completeSingle: false,            
            tables: getcontent()
        });
    }
}

function getcontent(){
return  content;
}
```